# Precompile mustache templates or load externally?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mustache

It would be useful to have a Coffeescript include function so it could load the external mustache templates when compiling in javascript and not clutter the coffee files.

Actually you can load .mustache files at runtime but you need to call them with an ajax request with some performance penalities involved.

I would like to precompile some static mustache templates and include them in generated javascript function that could be [Stitched](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch) and compressed in a single file.

Is there a project or a script for that?

Answer (score 7):

I think this solution for you, javascript template precompiller for mustache and othe template engines https://github.com/kupriyanenko/jsttojs

for example, use with command line

```
jsttojs templates compiled/templates/index.js --ext mustache --watch
```

or use solution for grunt, [grunt-jsttojs](https://github.com/kupriyanenko/grunt-jsttojs)

Comment: Link only answers are not welcome in Stack Overflow. Please add information here.

Comment: They're welcome, of course. But it is nice to have the answer brought to you, and also archived on SO in case the linked-to solution changes / 404's or anything else that could make having just a link be not useful.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-mustache" id="tid...">
  ... mustache template ...
</script>
```

to include your templates in dedicated script blocks rather than as strings in code.
`getElementByID()` + `innerHtml()` will give you its source that you can use.

About the Mustache in general - you cannot compile it strictly speaking. Templates get interpreted each time you "instantiate" the template.

If you do need to compile them then consider use of my Kite engine: 
http://code.google.com/p/kite/ or any other compileable templates:
http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/99

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, this is something we do where I work. All the templates go in a single html file and get's inserted into the dom at build time. Each template is stored in a script tag of type unknown so the browser just ignores it. Then you can reference them using selectors.

```
<script type="unknown" id="id_of_template">
  <ul>
  {{#words}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
  {{/words}}
  </ul>
</script>

render = (template) ->
  view =
    words: [ 'hello', 'there' ]
  template = $('#' + template).html()
  html = Mustache.to_html template, view
```

John Resig has a good article on the technique http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: another answer talks about using "text/x-mustache" as script type. why not do this?

Comment: No reason to do or not do it. The type will still not be recognised, but if it makes things clearer that it's a Mustache template then that works.

Comment: i thought so.. just a matter of documentation almost at that point

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at doing something similar. I haven't tried this yet, but it seems like you could use Node.js and [Mu](https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu), the Mustache build for Node.js, to do this. Pseudo-JS code...

```
var compiledTemplate = Mu.compile("myTemplateFile.html")
fs.writeFile("myCompiledTemplate.js", compiledTemplate.toString());
```

Comment: It seems that also Twitter has some interesting stuff like this: http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/

Answer (score 1):

Twitter's library [Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/) does the job.

Answer (score -1):

You can [render a template string included directly in your source using Mustache.to_html()](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-using-the-mustache-template-library/), if that helps.